# insert update multiple rows mysql

Tags: mysql, on-duplicate-key, multiple-records, multiple-insert

I need to add multiple records to a mysql database. I tried with multiple queries and its working fine, but not efficient. So I tried it with just one query like below,

```
INSERT INTO data (block, length, width, rows) VALUES
    ("BlockA", "200", "10", "20"),
    ("BlockB", "330", "8", "24"),
    ("BlockC", "430", "7", "36")
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    block=VALUES(block),
    length=VALUES(length),
    width=VALUES(width),
    rows=VALUES(rows)
```

But it always update the table (columns are block_id, block, length, width, rows).
Should I do any changes on the query with adding **block_id** also. **block_id** is the primary key. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the keys of the 'data' table ?

Comment: post is updated (block_id is the primary key)

Comment: I've run your query without any problem, are you sure you don't have other keys defined with the data table ? And also make sure you have 'auto increment' set for the id field

Answer (score 1):

I've run your query without any problem, are you sure you don't have other keys defined with the data table ? And also make sure you have 'auto increment' set for the id field. without auto_increment, the query always update existing row

******* *Updated* **************

Sorry I've mistaken your questions. Yes, with only one auto_increment key, you query will always insert new rows instead of updating existing one ( because the primary key is the only way to detect 'existing' / duplication ), since the key is auto_increment, there's never a duplication if the primary key is not given in the insert query.

I think what you want to achieve is different, you might want to set up composite unique key on all fields (i.e. block, field, width, rows )

By the way, i've set up a SQL fiddle for you.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e7216/1

The syntax to add the unique key:

```
CREATE TABLE `data` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`block` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`length` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`width` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`rows` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `uniqueme` (`block`,`length`,`width`,`rows`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: block_id is the only id is there. Also its auto increment. When I run this query again, its adding those data again instead of updating.